# Powershell - Get list of subfolders but include parent folder in it

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I have a script that for a given folder looks for all the subfolders recursively and in each subfolder does something to XML files that are inside.

```
foreach ($folderItem in ($folderItems = Get-ChildItem -Path $initialPath -Recurse -Directory)) {
Write-Host("Doing something with $folderItem")
}
```

Just now I got a call from a user saying it doesn't work. So, instead of the folder, containing subfolders with XML files, she was feeding one of the subfolders (apparently she wanted only that subfolder's XML files processed). Naturally, that subfolder didn't have any other subfolders in it so

```
$folderItems = Get-ChildItem -Path $initialPath -Recurse -Directory
```

was empty.

Now, I'm thinking - how can I get an object of type DirectoryInfo (that's what `Get-ChildItem` returns) and manually add a folder to it - so when iterating through it, it would include that  folder as well (in my case folder with `$initialPath` as path)? I can't just attach folder object to it:

> Method invocation failed because [System.IO.DirectoryInfo] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'.

One of the ways - maybe get parent folder for my folder, and then run `Get-ChildItem` on it - but how to filter out any siblings to my folder?

Comment: `@( Get-Item $initialPath; Get-ChildItem $initialPath .... )` should be the easy workaround

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Yeah, I'm thinking the same way, doing this for now:
```
$parentItem = Get-Item -Path $initialPath
$folderItems = Get-ChildItem -Path $initialPath -Recurse -Directory; 
$folderItemsArray+=$parentItem
$folderItemsArray+=$folderItems
```

Comment: I like your syntax better though.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon you essentially answered my question - post it as answer if you care about it being accepted as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so me and @Santiago in comments came to the same solution essentially.

```
$folderItems = @(Get-Item -Path $initialPath; Get-ChildItem -Path $initialPath -Recurse -Directory)
foreach ($folderItem in $folderItems) {
Write-Host("Doing something with $folderItem")
}
```

`$folderItem` in this case is an array, but looks like I can iterate through each item in array correctly still (meaning that it iterates through each folder object). And `$folderItems.Count` gives not the number of objects in the array (2) but total number of folders.
I need that since I output progress of the task.
Awesome!